# Using LINQ how can I prioritise an IEnumerable based on ranges?

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

If my data is a `List<Cat>` and each Cat has an age of 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

I want to re-order the list according to the ranges 1-3, 4-8, 9-10

such that the resulting list will be

3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 10, 9

How can I do that?

I first considered creating three queries:

```
var band1 = myList.Where(c => c <= 3);
var band2 = myList.Where(c => c => 4 && c <= 8);
var band3 = myList.Where(c => c >= 9);
```

but then I don't know how to combine the results using LINQ, as I have three `IEnumerable<Cat>`.

What's the correct method to use, or do I have to use a `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894.aspx).

```
var band1 = myList.Where(c => c <= 3);
var band2 = myList.Where(c => c => 4 && c <= 8);
var band3 = myList.Where(c => c >= 9);

var result = band1.Concat(band2).Concat(band3);
```

Comment: Nailed it. For some reason I thought I had to use a select or something more complicated. Thank you!

Comment: @SLC: If you have a desire to use `SelectMany`, or if you have an *arbitrary* number of sequences to concatenate, you can easily do so with `SelectMany` like this : `(new[] {band1, band2, band3}).SelectMany(x=>x)`.  Or in query expression notation `from x in new []{band1, band2, band3} from y in x select y`.  (This illustrates the more general principle that *all LINQ operations on sequences can be implemented using SelectMany*.)

Comment: Or, if you wanna get really nerdy, it represents how all monads can be represented using the bind monad in conjunction with some lesser-order function. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `GetRange(Cat cat)` method order your list by it:

```
myCatList.OrderBy(cat=>GetRange(cat));
```

Comment: +1 Just different "insertion point", create a method (or an extension method) to return the ordering (range) then go with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would use a single LINQ statement to do what you're asking for.

```
var ordered = items
    .OrderBy(x => {
        if(x <= 3) return 0;
        if(x <= 8) return 1;
        return 2;
    })
    .ThenByDescending(x => x);
```

Alternatively (assuming the items are already in descending order):

```
var ordered = myList
    .OrderBy(x => {
        if (x <= 3) { return 1; }
        if (x <= 8) { return 2; }
        return 3;
    });
```

Comment: Don't use multiple order bys, you want to do an order by and then a `ThenBy`.

Comment: Oops. The Descending was an afterthought just to make sure the descending order wasn't implicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
//define your ranges  
var ranges = new[] { 3,8,10};

var grouped = listOfCats.GroupBy( x => ranges.FirstOrDefault( r => r >= x.Age ) );
```

Comment: You then need to flatten the groups out to get the desired ordered result: `.SelectMany(group => group.OrderByDescending(cat => cat));`  You also don't handle the case of any invalid ranges well; adding in support for that would add quite a bit of complexity to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to concat the `IEnumerable<int>` with `IEnumerable<int>.Concat()`

```
var band1 = myList.Where(c => c <= 3);
var band2 = myList.Where(c => c >= 4 && c <= 8);
var band3 = myList.Where(c => c >= 9);

List<int> finalList = band1.Concat(band2).Concat(band3).ToList();
```